Bazel bash completion when installed with bazelisk
If you open the bazel website you can read that the recommended way to install Bazel is with bazelisk

So following the instructions I've downloaded the bazelisk release from github, renamed it to bazel and moved it somewhere that's under PATH.
Now I want the bash completions so that by writing partial paths and hitting tab I can see what are the available targets (and all that other nice things to have), so I opened the documentation and I can't find anything specific to the recommended installation procedure.

I also tried to use the fuzzyfinder (fzf) to see it this bazel-complete.bash was somewhere on my machine but I couldn't find it.
How do I have bash completions for Bazel when I install it using bazelisk?
